# Creating/removing directory using assembler (tasm) on windows

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, mkdir, tasm

I have to write a TASM program which creates and removes directory, but I found example of creating file only.

```
model small
.data
    handle dw 0
    filename db "file2.txt",0
.stack 256
.code
main:

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah,3ch 
    mov cx,1         
    lea dx,filename 
    int 21h 
    jc exit

    mov handle,ax
exit:
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
end main
```

How i can modify this code for creating directory instead of file? And how I can remove created firectory?

Comment: *int 21h* this is not windows. use `CreateDirectoryW`

Comment: The function code for creating a directory using [DOS `int 21h` is `39h`](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah39).

Comment: Your example is for DOS, it will run in 32bit Windows when you use DOS function [CREATE SUBDIRECTORY](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2775.htm) and [REMOVE SUBDIRECTORY](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2776.htm). You should update tags on your question. Or, if you need a PE program native for MS Windows, search for better examples of 32bit protected-mode programs.

Comment: Can TASM even make native *Windows* executables, not just DOS?  A Windows program would use `.386` / `.model flat,stdcall` I think.  So it seems you're actually making a pure DOS program.  If you happen to run it on an old / 32-bit Windows system, it may run under NTVDM.  So you should fix your tags, and check a list of DOS system calls.  The necessary calls should be listed right next to the ones for creating a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use masm and winapi. Here is the my sample code

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
option  casemap:none
includelib kernel32.lib
includelib shell32.lib
include windows.inc
include kernel32.inc

.const
    sDir db 'folder', 0
    
.code
    Main PROC
        invoke CreateDirectoryA, OFFSET sDir, NULL
        invoke Sleep, 2000d
        invoke RemoveDirectoryA, OFFSET sDir
        invoke Sleep, 2000d
        invoke ExitProcess, NULL
    Main ENDP

end Main
```